# Fullcalendar with date range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar, daterangepicker

I want to have a datepicker range on my Fullcalendar. I've seen some posts where you could pick a date with a datepicker, but I would like the user to be able to pick the start and end date.

[image: datepicker (1 date only)]

My fullcalendar looks like the following image, and I would like to add the datepickers on the red square.

[image]

This is the code I'm using. How/where can I add the datepickers?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            eventClick: function(event, element) {
                event.title = prompt('Event Title:',event.title );
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var d = new Date(dateText);
                $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <div id='datepicker'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't that work? What's the issue you're facing? Where's your code? Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I already edited my question @milz

Comment: didn't you find this in the jquery datepicker docs? https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range. 3 seconds of searching on google revealed it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's the work for you. But first, a few notes on your question:

1. If you want to do that with `prompt` you'll need to have three `prompts` (one for the title, other for the start and other for the end). And you should now that's not easy to customize a prompt.
2. You should have picked a datepicker library to use

Now, an explanation of the code below:

1. I'm using [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples) to request data from the user
2. I'm using [Bootstrap Eonasdan Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), with no options (you should customize this for your needs)
3. The idea is to open the modal when the user selects a date, fill the data in, click on the "save" button, add the event to fullcalendar, clear the modal's fields and close the dialog.

First, you need to write down the HTML for the modal, as such

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create new event</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-4" for="title">Event title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-4" for="starts-at">Starts at</label>
                        <input type="text" name="starts_at" id="starts-at" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-4" for="ends-at">Ends at</label>
                        <input type="text" name="ends_at" id="ends-at" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

You javascript should be updated to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            // Display the modal.
            // You could fill in the start and end fields based on the parameters
            $('.modal').modal('show');

        },
        eventClick: function(event, element) {
            // Display the modal and set the values to the event values.
            $('.modal').modal('show');
            $('.modal').find('#title').val(event.title);
            $('.modal').find('#starts-at').val(event.start);
            $('.modal').find('#ends-at').val(event.end);

        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events

    });

    // Bind the dates to datetimepicker.
    // You should pass the options you need
    $("#starts-at, #ends-at").datetimepicker();

    // Whenever the user clicks on the "save" button om the dialog 
    $('#save-event').on('click', function() {
        var title = $('#title').val();
        if (title) {
            var eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: $('#starts-at').val(),
                end: $('#ends-at').val()
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
        }
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

        // Clear modal inputs
        $('.modal').find('input').val('');

        // hide modal
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

And this is a start for you. There's a lot you should do to improve this. Note that when you edit an event, this will create a new one, but I leave you to figure that out.

For your convenience, I've created [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/fotLoLy9/) where you can view this working and the dependencies used.